# Head note in table including equation

Tags: tables

Please I want to replicate this table:

[image]

The only difficulty here is the head note of the table which includes an equation. Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try with `threeparttablex`, which is an extension of `threeparttable` to longtables, and lets you insert table notes anywhere you please (not necessarily after the table itself).

Answer (score 3):

One can use normal text inside the `table` environment. This text may also contain an equation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{caption text}
\centering
head note including an equation
\begin{equation*}
abc
\end{equation*}
more text

\begin{tabular}{cc}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also add three rows above the `\toprule` of the table, span all cells in a row with a `\multicolumn`, use a `p`-column for the text. The MWE below illustrates this, even though the text and figures etc. is not from your tabular.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, amsmath}

\begin{document}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\centering\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}p{2cm}cccccccr@{}}
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{15cm}@{}}{The multicolumn command makes an entry that spans several columns. The first mandatory argument, cols, specifies the number of columns to span. The second mandatory argument, pos, specifies the formatting of the entry; c for centered, l for flushleft, r for flushright. The third mandatory argument, text, specifies what text to put in the entry.} \\
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{15cm}@{}}{\begin{equation*}[i\delta, 1/2\sqrt{3}+i(1+2\delta)/2]\, \text{and}\, [i(1+\delta), 1/2\sqrt{3}+i(1+2\delta)/2\end{equation*}}\\
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{15cm}@{}}{The multicolumn command makes an entry that spans several columns. The first mandatory argument, cols, specifies the number of columns to span. The second mandatory argument, pos, specifies the formatting of the entry; c for centered, l for flushleft, r for flushright. The third mandatory argument, text, specifies what text to put in the entry.The multicolumn command makes an entry that spans several columns. The first mandatory argument, cols, specifies the number of columns to span. The second mandatory argument, pos, specifies the formatting of the entry; c for centered, l for flushleft, r for flushright. The third mandatory argument, text, specifies what text to put in the entry.}\\
\toprule
Hours of incubation  & pH\,5.0 & pH\,6.0 & pH\,7.0 & pH\,7.5 & pH\,8.0 & pH\,8.5 & pH\,9.0 & pH\,10\\\midrule
12 & 0.00 & 0.0238 & 0.4036 & 0.4397 & 0.4493 & 0.4349 & 0.3191 & 0.005 \\
24  &   0.00  &     0.1319 &    1.7929 &    1.8368 &    1.8629 &    1.8032 &    1.4087 &    0.035\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]